# How does the Suggested Edit review process work?

Tags: support, editing, review-queues

I recently suggested edits to the answer to this question [Declination Diagram](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/81625/declination-diagram).
(They were *suggested* because I don't have enough reputation to make them stick.)

Like many Q&A, there were some subtle issues involved and I thought I could clarify some things in the answer by adding/deleting a word or two, and by adding *emphasis* here or there -- no change in meaning, just a small improvement. Of course, that was my opinion but not the reviewer's -- the suggestions weren't applied.

Is there any way to see what happened? Months ago, my suggested edit to an answer on StackOverflow was rejected as insignificant (I only corrected a link!) but at least I was informed of what happened (votes for/against and reason).

I don't wish to complain about that individual incident -- I'd like to understand the process of reviewing suggested edits.

**addendum**

Thanks to whuber's comment, I learned how to investigate the status of suggested edits, and posted my findings as an answer, even though it only touched on the issue.

Now there's been a second incident -- suggested edits to the question https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/81754/any-update-on-having-a-similar-how-smooth-line-tool-from-arcgis-in-postgis that were rejected -- I've decided to "refresh" my question about the edit review process.

My suggestion had one approval and one rejection. (The rejection was from the OP -- I don't know if that means anything.) This time I feel stronger that it was a useful edit but I don't even know who can even review the suggestion or for how long the process can/must continue.

So my question is **How does the whole suggested edits review process work?** or Where is it explained?

Comment: Have you reviewed your actions in your [user profile](http://gis.stackexchange.com/users/3195/martin-f?tab=activity&sort=suggestions)? Full records of your suggestions and how they were moderated are available there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work/76284#76284) for a comprehensive overview of suggested edits on StackOverflow. Note that those rules will not be identical to GIS.SE, but they are pretty close.

Note that GIS.SE moderators can cast an immediate binding vote on suggested edits, which is not listed in "Who can vote on a suggested edit?" at that link.

Answer (score 6):

Somebody has to tell you, or you stumble upon it by accident:

- Click ***your icon*** (top menu bar) to see your "user profile".
- Click **activity** (fourth menu bar).
- Click **all** (fifth menu bar) to see your suggestions and those that were accepted.
- Click **suggested edit** on suggestions that appear not to have been accepted, to see reason.